# What are interleaved layers of convolutions?

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

In the [FaceNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832v3.pdf), they describe the [Zeiler&Fergus model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.2901) like this:

> [...] the
>   Zeiler&Fergus model which consists of multiple interleaved
>   layers of convolutions, [...]

What do they mean by **interleaved**? How does that compare to the [inception layers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842)?

Especially, as the Zeiler&Fergus paper states

> We use standard fully supervised convnet models
>   throughout the paper, as defined by (LeCun et al.,
>   1989) and (Krizhevsky et al., 2012).
>
> [...]
>
> The top few layers of the network are conventional
>   fully-connected networks and the final layer is
>   a softmax classifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford dictionary explains ["interleave"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interleave) as

> Place something between the layers of (something)

or in the context of telecommunication, as

> Mix (digital signals) by alternating between them.

In the [FaceNet paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832v3.pdf), Schroff *et. al* describe their first architecture as

> multiple interleaved layers of convolutions, non-linear activations, local response normalizations, and max pooling layers

which means they create a CNN by "altering between" these layer types (e.g. `Conv -> Pool -> Conv -> Pool -> ..`). Or with the wording of the first definition, you "place one layer" of each type "between" the other existing layers (i.e. start with a couple of `Conv` layers, then place `Pool` layer between two `Conv` layers, and so on).
The final architecture would look somewhat like this:

```
Conv -> ReLu -> LRN -> Pool -> Conv -> ReLu -> LRN -> Pool -> Conv -> ...
```

So, this "interleaved" CNN is a network where the different layer types are applied in *series*, layer-by-layer.
As a comparison, in ["inception" type CNN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842), you apply the different layer types in *parallel* (the graphic below is 1 layer):

```
              +---> Conv 3x3 ---+
              |                 |
prev layer ---+---> Conv 5x5 ---+---> next layer
              |                 |
              +---> Pool 3x3 ---+
```